# SoapUI on windows 10 - high DPI/4K scaling issue

Tags: soapui

SoapUI doesn't seem to be DPI-Aware
and displays too small on my high DPI screen (tiny text and buttons). Other applications are running fine (screen resolution 3840 x 2160).

[image: toosmall]

*Version*: SoapUI 5.1.2
*OS*: Windows 10

I have tried:

- Configure SoapUI to run with "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" - some parts of SoapUI are looking even bigger and don't display properly [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWNOB.png)
- Changing resolution
- Changing font size (Preferences > Editor Settings > Select font...)

Therefore I assume, that SoapUI pretends to be DPI-Aware, but does not really scale up itself. Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is the workaround until the developers get round to making a version that is DPI-Aware.

**Step 1: Add a registry key**
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\PreferExternalManifest (DWORD) to 1

**Step 2: Add a manifest file 'SoapUI-5.2.1.exe.manifest' in the same directory as  'SoapUI-5.2.1.exe'**

Content of manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <description>eclipse</description>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel xmlns:ms_asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"
                    level="asInvoker" ms_asmv3:uiAccess="false">
                </requestedExecutionLevel>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
            <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

**Correct DPI scaling:**
[image: corect]

Comment: should this work with ClearTypes? Because I tried, and there is no difference. I am using a scaling of 120.

Comment: Never mind. It does work. I was trying it in the wrong directory, where the shortcut is, not the exe,

Comment: I had the same problem as Tulio C. **The executable of SoapUI is in the bin directory!**

Comment: reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide /v PreferExternalManifest /d 1 /t REG_DWORD

Comment: Obviously you have to change the manifest file name to mirror the SoapUI version number or it won't work

Comment: As above, I had to use SoapUI-5.3.0.exe.manifest for my installed version. Then it worked.

Comment: For me with version 5.50, it does not work. SoapUI shows for about 1 second in the correct scaling, but then seems to switch to super-small again.

Comment: Worked for SoapUI 5.2.1 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: More Explanation is here : https://danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/

Answer (score 76):

On Windows 10, it now works by setting the scaling in the properties of the SoapUI.exe

[image: SoapUI Compability Properties for scaling]

from https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/SoapUI-editor-appearing-small-on-high-resolution-monitor/m-p/142113/highlight/true#M24163

Comment: This doesn't require registry editing and works for non-admin users as well. And is supported in the current version of Windows 10 as well. +1

Comment: This is what worked for me on my Surfacebook Pro, though it did request admin permissions, not sure if that's just my network though

Comment: This option has now moved to a submenu, but same settings sill apply.

Answer (score 8):

I did as below, it works fine after restart SoapUI

Properties -> Compatibility -> Change high DPI settings -> Overide high ... -> System

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You also can use this command to create registry key:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide /v PreferExternalManifest /d 1 /t REG_DWORD
```

[Source](http://soapfault.com/blog/2016/02/soapui-in-high-dpi/)

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated in July 2020]** : this workaround is only applicable for SOAP UI 5.5 (and lower).
SOAP UI 5.6 (and higher) contains Java 12, so it now supports HiDPI natively (without pixelated font rendering).

Java does support Hi DPI from version 9.

1. Download and install Java 9 or higher
2. Edit "C:\Program Files\SoapUI\bin\soapui.bat" and add the line at the beginning :

   set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9"
3. In file "C:\Program Files\SoapUI\bin\soapui.bat", add at the beginning of the line the option "--permit-illegal-access" :

   set JAVA_OPTS= --permit-illegal-access -Xms128m -Xmx1024m
4. Rename C:\Program Files\SoapUI\jre into C:\Program Files\SoapUI\jre.disabled
5. Start "soapui.bat"

Hint : use the fixed-size font "Consolas" in "Editor Settings"

Note : tested with Windows 10 "Creators Update" (build 1703)

[image: Screenshot of SOAP-UI in Hi DPI]

Comment: I'm getting "JAVA_HOME is not set, unexpected results may occur"... And the app exit.

Comment: Please check that the JAVA_HOME you have specified at step 2 is the correct path to Java 9 on your system.

Comment: using 5.7.0 and it still has the same issue on win 11

Answer (score 1):

This will fix the SOAPUI issues on Windows 10 with high resolution screen 3840 X 2160.

1. Goto installation directory of SOAP UI
   C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin
2. Right click on SoapUI-5.4.0.exe and click on compatibility tab
3. Tick mark yes on checkbox: Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by:
4. Select System from dropdown
5. Click apply on it.

Screenshot of SOAP UI Compatibility mode:
[image: Screenshot of SOAP UI Compatibility mode]

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as Rudi, but the UI is a bit different. (I wanted to add this to the comment, but I need more reputation for that.)

This works for me even on dual monitor, one high DPI and one normal DPI.

I used the System (Enhanced), but both System and System (Enhanced) work.

[Different Windows 10 UI for changing the high DPI settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImaxM.png)