# SoapUI not scaling on 4K screens in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, soapui, scaling

It is a known issue that SoapUI doesn't scale in Windows 10. There used to be a solution for this: 
[SoapUI on windows 10 - high DPI/4K scaling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709583/soapui-on-windows-10-high-dpi-4k-scaling-issue)

Since the Windows 10 anniversary update this solution is broken. I use SoapUI for my work and it's just not ok to work with any more.

Does anyone know another way of solving this?

Comment: Have you logged a bug with the SoapUI team?

Comment: I'm so happy. I have finally found a solution that works after the anniversary update. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6cCjsYX98Y

Answer (score 2):

Change the setting for soapui shown as below:

> Right click on `Soapui Icon -> Properties -> Compatibility Tab` -> check `Disable scaling on high DPI settings`

Comment: Hi Rao, that didn't work on a surface pro 4 at least. Anyway today I found a solution that does work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6cCjsYX98Y